# Creating a link to a contact in aura component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, contact, aura

I have the following code in aura component

```
<aura:component controller="contactSearch" implements="force:appHostable" >
    <aura:attribute access="public" name="maxResults" type="Integer" default="10" />
    <aura:attribute name="contacts" type="Contact[]" />
<ul>
<aura:iteration items="{!v.contacts}" var="contact">
    <li class="minli"> <h3><a onclick="{!c.navigateToRecord}" style="width:100%;"> {!contact.Name}</a></h3> </li>
</aura:iteration>
</ul>
```

In the ComponentController I have

```
({
       navigateToRecord : function(component, event, helper) {
         var navEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
         if(navEvent){
             //console.log(component.get("v.contacts").Id);
             navEvent.setParams({
                  recordId: component.get("v.contacts").Id,
                  slideDevName: "detail"
             });
             navEvent.fire();   
         }
         else{
            //window.location.href = '/one/one.app#/sObject/'+component.get("v.contacts").Id+'/view'
         }
    }
})
```

What I want is to redirect to the Detail page of the Controller whose name is clicked

I want to add a link to the contact in the contact name
Can anyone tell me how to do that?
I am very new to lightning and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: is your component inside `/one/one.app` container ?

Comment: It is within a aura component

Comment: are you using the aura:component in SF1 or Lightning Experience(in record detail page) or Standalone App?

Comment: It is a stand alone app

Comment: I have posted the answer.Please check it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your component runs in `one/one.app` container(SF1 or LEX - Record Detail page ), Tushar Sharma's solution will work for you, because the it is handled by the `one/one.app` itself.

Below is the statement on the doc:

> e.force:XXX event is handled by the one.app container.
>   It’s supported in Lightning Experience and Salesforce1 only. If used
>   outside of Lightning Experience or Salesforce1, this event won’t be
>   handled automatically. To use this event outside of one.app, create
>   and wire up an event handler of your own.

One approach is that,just check whether the `e.force:navigateToSObject` is available or not(which won't inside a standalone app), and switch the navigation logic.

**Component:**

```
<aura:component controller="contactSearch" implements="force:appHostable" >
    <aura:attribute access="public" name="maxResults" type="Integer" default="10" />
    <aura:attribute name="contacts" type="Contact[]" />
    <ul>
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.contacts}" var="contact indexVar="index">
        <li class="minli"> 
            <h3>
                <a onclick="{!c.navigateToRecord}" style="width:100%;" data-index="{!index}">{!contact.Name}</a>
            </h3>
        </li>
    </aura:iteration>
    </ul>
</aura:component>
```

**Controller:**

```
({
    navigateToRecord : function(component, event, helper) {
        var idx = event.target.getAttribute('data-index');
        var contact = component.get("v.contacts")[idx];
        var navEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
        if(navEvent){
            navEvent.setParams({
                  recordId: contact.Id,
                  slideDevName: "detail"
            });
            navEvent.fire(); 
        }
        else{
            window.location.href = '/one/one.app#/sObject/'+contact.Id+'/view'
        }
    }
})
```

Another approach is, you can wire up an event handler of your own for the `e.force:navigateToSObject`, like this:

**Component:**

```
<aura:component controller="contactSearch" implements="force:appHostable" >
    <aura:attribute access="public" name="maxResults" type="Integer" default="10" />
    <aura:attribute name="contacts" type="Contact[]" />
     <aura:handler event="force:navigateToSObject" action="{!c.navigateToRecord}"/>
    <ul>
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.contacts}" var="contact indexVar="index">
        <li class="minli"> 
            <h3>
                <a onclick="{!c.viewRecord}" style="width:100%;" data-index="{!index}">{!contact.Name}</a>
            </h3>
        </li>
    </aura:iteration>
    </ul>
</aura:component>
```

**Controller:**

```
({
    viewRecord : function(component, event, helper) {
         var navEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
         var idx = event.target.getAttribute('data-index');
         var contact = component.get("v.contacts")[idx];
         if(navEvent){
             navEvent.setParams({
                  recordId: contact.Id,
                  slideDevName: "detail"
             });
             navEvent.fire(); 
         }

    },
    navigateToRecord : function(component, event, helper) {
        var recordId = event.getParam("recordId");
        window.location.href = '/one/one.app#/sObject/'+recordId+'/view';
    },

})
```

Comment: I tried your approach, it is still throwing me an error. it is throwing an error in salesforce 1 as well.. Help!!

Comment: can you update the question with the code you tried?

Comment: I have updated the question. It is not being visible yet. Hopefully it would be visible soon @Praveen

Comment: @Rimii I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this in Lightning.

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="contact" type="contact" required="true" />
    <a onclick="{!c.navigateToRecord}" style="width:100%;"> 
        View Record
    </a>
</aura:component>
```

redirectToSobject Controller

```
({
    navigateToRecord : function(component, event, helper) {
         var navEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
         navEvent.setParams({
              recordId: component.get("v.contact").Id,
              slideDevName: "detail"
         });
         navEvent.fire(); 
    }
})
```

So basically you can use `e.force:navigateToSObject` to redirect to detailpage.

Comment: this won't work outside of `one/one.app` container

Comment: It will work in lightning.

Comment: if you use it an Standalone App, `var navEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");` returns `undefined`

Comment: It is throwing undefined error. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: @Rimii you need to check what i undefined here. maybe you are not getting sobject here.

Comment: @TusharSharma will you please check my code and tell me where am I going wrong