# Unable to use built in events (Event Reference)

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Salesforce has functions that do a lot of basic web app functionality for you, called Event Reference. They can be found here https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_events.htm

On the editRecord Event Reference, found here
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_editRecord.htm

essentaily, I create a

```
<ui:button label="Edit" press="{!c.editRecord}"/>
```

on my component, reference the attribute on the page and add the function from the docs in the controller

```
editRecord : function(component, event, helper) {
    var editRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:editRecord");

    console.log("record id is: " + component.get("v.item.Id"));
    console.log("editRecordEvent value is: " + editRecordEvent);

    editRecordEvent.setParams({
        "recordId": component.get("v.item.Id")
    });

    editRecordEvent.fire();
}
```

correct?

Here is the odd thing. From the console.logs, I get the record id, but the editRecordEvent returns undefined. What is going on? Is there something I need to reference in my component to use Event Reference?

[image]

Comment: Look at this [answer](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/130053/20830) this will help.This solution applies to all `e.force:XXX` events

Comment: @Praveen I'm iterating over a component. Do I put the handler outside the iteration or put it in the iterated component?

Comment: If you get the id in the iterated (child) component,pass the id to the parent component through component event.So obvious place to put the handler is on the parent component.

Comment: Can't get it to work :(

Comment: This seems too messy for an out-of-the-box event.

Comment: As far as i know, above is the only way to do it.Please updated the question with code you tried so that i can help

Comment: I've asked the team that owns force:editRecord to chime in here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't state details of how you are using this component, but here is a possible explanation.

There are a number of features in Lightning components that exist only in certain web containers...in other words certain lightning apps.

The `force:editRecord` event is one of these.

Essentially when you invoke a component in the context of the URL `[hostname]/one/one.app` (the URL for Salesforce1 mobile and for Lightning Experience), there are a bunch of resources that are martialled up and put in place a developer can make use of without any extra work.

From the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_editRecord.htm):

> This event is handled by the one.app container. It’s supported in Lightning Experience and Salesforce1 only. If used outside of Lightning Experience or Salesforce1, this event won’t be handled automatically. To use this event outside of one.app, create and wire up an event handler of your own.

However, if use a different application context (either because I want to create my own Lightning app, or because I am doing some initial testing with a Lightning Component perhaps), those events are not supported, and thus not available to retrieve from the Aura context at runtime.

A complete list of these components is in this [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/128093/revisions) related to another question Lightning for Visualforce.