# Lightning controller error

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am working on a lightning component where on click contact link I have to open that contact in edit mode. But throwing this error:
[image]

Please find my code below:
    I am using it in :

```
<aura:component > 
    <aura:attribute name="showcontact" type="Contact[]"/>

    <table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--cell-buffer" style="margin-top:50px;"> 
        <thead> 

        <div style="text-align:center;font-size:25px">
            Selected Contacts
        </div>

        <tr class="slds-text-heading--label">
            <th scope="col">
                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Contact Name"><b>Contact Name</b></div>
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Phone"><b>Phone</b></div>
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Email"><b>Email</b></div>
            </th> 
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.showcontact}" var="con">
            <tr>
                <th> 
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="{!c.editContact}" data-value="{!con.Id}">
                        {!con.Name}
                    </a>
                </th>
                <th> 
                    <div class="slds-truncate" >
                            {!con.Phone}
                    </div> 
                </th>
                <th>        
                    <div class="slds-truncate">
                        {!con.Email}
                    </div> 
                </th>
            </tr> 
        </aura:iteration>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</aura:component>
```

Controller:

```
({
    editContact: function (component, event, helper) {
        var rectarget = event.currentTarget;
        var idstr = rectarget.getAttribute("data-value"); 
        console.log('****'+idstr)
        var editRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:editRecord");
        editRecordEvent.setParams({
            "recordId": idstr
        });
        editRecordEvent.fire();        
    }
})
```

Comment: whats the value you are getting in idstr...please use console.log('****',idstr).??? and alsp try o use like this  var rectarget = event. event.target.Id;

Comment: I am getting contact id here.

Comment: make on Id hard code and check that. I think that you maynot get that error (for testing purpose )something like this:<a onclick="{!c.editContact}" data-conId="0037F00000O7Dj7QAF">0037F00000O7Dj7QAF</a>

Comment: Please note: `This event is handled by the one.app container. It’s supported in Lightning Experience, the Salesforce app, and Lightning communities.` If you are not in this context, this event won't be available

Comment: I am using it in : 
        <aura:application extends="force:slds">
              <c:ShowContactsOnClickAccount/>
      </aura:application>
How can I show it here ?

Comment: Similar question has been answered here. Please refer. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/131621/unable-to-use-built-in-events-event-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are adding lightning component to a Lightning app and viewing lightning app from developer console then e.force:editRecord do not work because force events are handled only in one/one.app. so please try to add a lightning component to the page using app builder.