# navigateTOsObjectNot Working-component not defined

Tags: lightning-aura-components

i have a lightning component which displays top 5 accounts.My requirement is ti when i click on a record i should navigate to detail page of the account.

I have written all the code and i can see the output. but when i click on the detail button of the record iam not able to navigate to detail page getting below error

> Uncaught Action failed: c$LightningForceNavigateToSObjectItem$controller$gotoDetail [TypeError: Cannot read property 'setParams' of undefined]
>   throws at https://varasales-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/ot_aUc3gWVJCViXm5-AclQ/aura_prod.js:1:27
>       at Object.gotoDetail (components/c/LightningForceNavigateToSObjectItem.js:22:15)
>       at gotoDetail (components/c/LightningForceNavigateToSObjectItem.js:10:16)
>       at G.qc (https://varasales-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/ot_aUc3gWVJCViXm5-AclQ/aura_prod.js:275:170)
>       at Array.c (https://varasales-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/ot_aUc3gWVJCViXm5-AclQ/aura_prod.js:228:170)
>       at https://varasales-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/ot_aUc3gWVJCViXm5-AclQ/aura_prod.js:265:155
>       at $.z.ab (https://varasales-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/ot_aUc3gWVJCViXm5-AclQ/aura_prod.js:522:141)
>       at O.M (https://varasales-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/ot_aUc3gWVJCViXm5-AclQ/aura_prod.js:264:81)
>       at Object.catchAndFireEvent (https://varasales-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/l/%7B%22mode%22%3A%22PROD%22%2C%22app%22%3A%22one%3Aone%22%2C%22fwuid%22%3A%22ot_aUc3gWVJCViXm5-AclQ%22%2C%22loaded%22%3A%7B%22APPLICATION%40markup%3A%2F%2Fone%3Aone%22%3A%22LTX5y5GOICnl_zeBOa0nnQ%22%7D%2C%22requestedLocales%22%3A%5B%22en_US%22%2C%22en%22%5D%2C%22ls%22%3A%22YN%22%7D/app.js:148:15)
>       at press (https://varasales-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/l/%7B%22mode%22%3A%22PROD%22%2C%22app%22%3A%22one%3Aone%22%2C%22fwuid%22%3A%22ot_aUc3gWVJCViXm5-AclQ%22%2C%22loaded%22%3A%7B%22APPLICATION%40markup%3A%2F%2Fone%3Aone%22%3A%22LTX5y5GOICnl_zeBOa0nnQ%22%7D%2C%22requestedLocales%22%3A%5B%22en_US%22%2C%22en%22%5D%2C%22ls%22%3A%22YN%22%7D/app.js:146:91)
>       at G.qc (https://varasales-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/ot_aUc3gWVJCViXm5-AclQ/aura_prod.js:275:170)

Please find my code below:

main component:LightningForceNavigateTosObjectDemo

*

```
<aura:component controller="NavigateToSObjectDemoController" implements="force:appHostable">
    <aura:attribute name="accounts" type="Account[]"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.doInit}" value="{!this}"/>
     <aura:dependency resource="markup://force:navigateToSObject" type="EVENT"/>
    <div id="aura:page">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="auraTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>No</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th colspan="3"></th>
             </tr>
            </thead>
         <tbody>
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.accounts}" var="item" indexVar="index">
                <c:LightningForceNavigateToSObjectItem item="{!item}" index="{!index+1}"/>
            </aura:iteration>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>


</aura:component>
```

*

```
its controller
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {

        helper.getAccounts(component);

    }
})
```

its helper

```
({
    getAccounts : function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.getAccounts");
       action.setCallback(this, function(a){
       component.set("v.accounts", a.getReturnValue());
 });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);


    }})
```

its apex class NavigateToSObjectDemoController

```
public class NavigateToSObjectDemoController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Account> getAccounts() {
        return [SELECT Name from Account];
    } 
}
```

other component which is referred in main component
LightningForceNavigateTosObjectItem

```
<aura:component >

    <aura:attribute name="item" type="account"/>
    <aura:attribute name="index" type="Integer"/>
    <tr>
        <td calss="indexCol">{!v.index}</td>
        <td>{!v.item.Name}</td>
        <td class="btnCol">
            <ui:button label="Detail" press="{!c.gotoDetail}"/>
        </td>
        <td class="btnCol">
            <ui:button label="Chatter" press="{!c.gotoChatter}"/>
        </td>
        <td class="btnCol">
            <ui:button label="Related" press="{!c.gotoRelated}"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</aura:component>
```

its controller

```
({
    gotoDetail : function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.gotoDetail(component);
    },
    gotoChatter : function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.gotoChatter(component);
    },
    gotoRelated : function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.gotoRelated(component);
    }
})
```

its helper

```
({
    gotoDetail : function() {
        var navEvt=$A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
        navEvt.setParams({
            "recordId":component.get("v.item.id"),
            "slideDevName":"detail"
        });
        navEvt.fire();
    },
    gotoChatter : function() {
        var navEvt=$A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
        navEvt.setParams({
            "recordId":component.get("v.item.id"),
            "slideDevName":"chatter"
        });
        navEvt.fire();
    },
    gotoRelated : function() {
        var navEvt=$A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
        navEvt.setParams({
            "recordId":component.get("v.item.id"),
            "slideDevName":"related"
        });
        navEvt.fire();
    },
})
```

pls share thoughts

Comment: Look at this [answer](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/130053/20830), it will help you out.

Comment: which section of code should i refer...I am not certain what is the problem in my code..pls help

Comment: we can access nested property Id using component.get("v.item.Id"). It would certainly work.

Comment: As Junaid pointed out, you are not passing the `component` to the helper method. Try printing the value of `component.get("v.item.Id")` in the browser log, to check if record Id is logged or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have'nt given **component** as a parameter in functions defined in the helper.

So the whole helper should be modified as follows.

```
({
    gotoDetail : function(component) {
       var navEvt=$A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
       navEvt.setParams({
           "recordId":component.get("v.item.Id"),
           "slideDevName":"detail"
       });
       navEvt.fire();
   },
   gotoChatter : function(component) {
       var navEvt=$A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
       navEvt.setParams({
           "recordId":component.get("v.item.Id"),
           "slideDevName":"chatter"
       });
       navEvt.fire();
   },
   gotoRelated : function(component) {
       var navEvt=$A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
       navEvt.setParams({
           "recordId":component.get("v.item.Id"),
           "slideDevName":"related"
       });
       navEvt.fire();
   }})
```

Comment: thanks for the answer now getting error of Uncaught Action failed: one$centerStage$controller$handleDelegatedEvent [TypeError: Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined]
throws at https://varasales-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/ot_aUc3gWVJCViXm5-AclQ/aura_prod.js:1:27

Comment: @junaid-p-khader,  we can access nested property `Id` using component.get("v.item.Id"). It would certainly work.Please correct it.

Comment: @junaid P Khader,praveen Thanks for the help it worked....appreciate ur help:)

Comment: @vara If this solves your issue, please mark it as the best answer.