# Previewing app through dev console vs viewing it through a tab in lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, lightning-experience

How does Salesforce handle opening a lightning app from developer console (vs) creating a tab view in lightning.

I created a sample app that has a button which calls the **e.force:navigateToList** event on press. When I open it in lightning mode as a tab the click event works as expected and navigates me to the contact list, but the same causes an error when I open through developer console preview link.

**Something has gone wrong. Error in $A.getCallback() [TypeError: Cannot read property 'setParams' of undefined]
Failing descriptor: {markup://prao6308:navigateappmaincomp}.
Please try again.**

As per docs: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_navigateToList.htm

> **This event is handled by the one.app container**. It’s supported in
>   Lightning Experience and Salesforce1 only.

**Does this mean the force:XXXX events will work only in Lightning only mode and cannot be tested using the preview button from dev console?** (or) is there something basic that I am overlooking about lightning architecture?

**

### component:

**

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable" controller="controllerforlistview">   
    <ui:button label="Go to second component" press="{!c.navigateToMyList}"/>
</aura:component>
```

### Controller:

```
({
    navigateToMyList : function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.getListViews");
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                var listviews = response.getReturnValue();
                var navEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToList");
                navEvent.setParams({
                    "listViewId": listviews.Id,
                    "listViewName": null,
                    "scope": "Contact"
                });
                navEvent.fire();
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }})
```

Ouput:

Comment: force events are handled in `one/one.app` container only.Look at this [answer](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/130053/20830), it will help.

Comment: @Praveen thats kinda what I understood, why take the pain of having a preview button that does nothing then is my question

Comment: Rao, I didn't understand what is been said in your comment regarding the preview button.